# Is it okay to ask for feedback on an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

Let's say some users were initially active on a question but then left (without favoriting) the question while I was writing an answer. Is it okay to use `@user` to ask for feedback on said answer? The OP was a bit slow to respond (which leaves me to think that he won't notice my answer for a while), and the two users who I would like to comment on my answer seem to know a lot about the subject. It seems like spamming/attention whoring, but at the same time I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my answer.

Comment: If you are just looking for feedback on your solution, I don't see a problem with asking.  But if they don't respond, continually pinging them until they do respond would be frowned upon.

Comment: Yup; what @psubsee2003 said. That's one of the main reasons for the @-reply. Just 1) keep it limited to posts where the user has actually been active and 2) don't keep bugging them if they don't reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in using @ to reply to somebody else when they are slow to respond to you. However, keep in mind that it can become annoying to continually use @-reply, as it will fill up their inbox with possibly-unwanted messages. If you need to continue to get feedback for a long time, I do not recommend putting it in the comments but opening up a new chat and getting feedback there. Long, winding comment threads are not a good idea on questions, as they clutter up the question.

Comment: Worth to mention that even 100 replies on same post will be "grouped" under the same inbox item for the target user.